# Time teaser - clock losing time

Tags: calculation-puzzle

I recall a question that went like this:

- If a clock is at noon on Sunday, and the clock loses 9 minutes per hour, what time will the clock next show the correct time?

How do you work that one out??

cheers!

Comment: To clarify this means that the minute hand moves 51 minutes forward every hour instead of 60.  Is this correct?

Comment: Not a brainteaser at all as the tag suggest. just simple math. Not even a puzzle I would say

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy I guess. it will be correct again when it is 12 hours behind. 12 hours = 720 minutes. 720 divided by 9 is 80. So in 80 hours it will be correct again. So that is Wednesday at 8PM